# Undefined php function http_post_data on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php, pecl

Added the following under `Dynamic Extensions` in both php.ini's (Apache's, and the normal one found with: `sudo updatedb && locate php.ini`)

```
extension=raphf.so
extension=propro.so
extension=http.so
```

Ran the following installs, which all worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev php5-dev php-pear
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

Yet testing it still fails

```
php -r 'http_post_data();'
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function http_post_data() in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `sudo pecl install pecl_http`
`pecl/pecl_http is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.4.3`

Comment: What if you try to uninstall first `pecl uninstall pecl_http` and then install again `pecl install pecl_http` ?

Comment: Did that, same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

Ran across the same issue myself.  http_post_data() is provided by **v1** of this PECL extension, not v2 which is the default to install.

Re-install via `pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6`

After that:

```
php -r 'http_post_data();'
PHP Warning:  http_post_data() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given in Command line code on line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu PHP usually comes with some help functions `php5enmod` and `php5dismod`.
These map to enabling modules by name found in `/etc/php5/mods-available` and symlinking them as appropriate to `/etc/php5/[SAPI]/conf.d`, where the sapi is usually "cli", "fpm", or "apache2".

I would check to make sure the ini files you referenced, presumably found in `/etc/php5/mods-available` have been symlinked to `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` and/or `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`. You can use `sudo php5enmod -s ALL mod_name_here` to create those symlinks for you for all SAPI's (cli, apache, etc). "mod_name_here" is usually the name of the INI file created minus the `.ini` extension portion.

I'm making some assumptions about your system though, for example I don't know if you've installed PHP from `apt-get`/`aptitude` or if you've compiled from source, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I installed PHP through `sudo tasksel`. 
It was nice to be introduced to `php5enmod` , but even with that, I still get `Undefined function`